# Unique fixed point in a group action

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions, fixed-points

I have been doing algebra exercises recently and I stumbled across this problem that I struggled to solve.

> Suppose a finite group $G$ acts on a finite set $A$ so that for every nontrivial $g \in G$ there exists a unique fixed point (i.e., there is exactly one $a \in A$, depending on $g$, such that $g(a) = a$). Prove that this fixed point is the same for all $g \in G$.

I had a feeling that we were supposed to use the orbit stabilizer theorem but I didn't know how. So I made the following attempt:

Suppose $|G|=n$ and suppose all $g_i\in G$ such that $g_i(a_0)=a_0\in A$ except for $m$ of them. Then $G=\{g_1,...,g_{k1},...,g_{km},...,g_n\}$ acts on $a_0$ will have the orbit $\{a_0,...,a_{k1},...,a_{km},...,a_0\}$. Then we let $G$ acts on $a_{k1}$ and get the orbit $\{a_1,a_2,...,a_0,a_{k1},...,a_n\}$. $a_0$ is in it because we have $g_{k1}^{-1}$ and $a_{k1}$ exists because these two orbits have $a_0$ in common$\Rightarrow$they are the same orbit. Moreover, $g_{k1}$ can't fix $a_{k1}$ therefore $\exists g_{kx}(a_{k1})=a_{k1}$.

This is the furthest I can get. I'm trying to force a contradiction by assuming the negative but got really stuck.

Could you give me some hints to push me forward? If this direction is totally wrong, what would be the correct path?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: A start: Consider for each $a$ the elements $G_a$ which fix $a.$ Each $G_a$ is a subgroup, and $G_a\cap G_b=\{e\}$ for any $a\neq b,$ by the condition of the problem, and every non-trivial element of $g$ is in exactly one $G_a.$

Comment: If $g$ is of order $k$ then each orbit of $g$ other than the fixed point must be of size $k.$ Otherwise, some $g^d$ has an additional fixed point for some $d\mid k.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews What do you mean by "orbit of g"?

Comment: Technically,  it is the orbits of the subgroup $\langle g\rangle$ generated by $G.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I just noticed how to solve this using Burnside's lemma which I don't know 13 hours ago.

Comment: But what is the contradiction though? I can't see any contradictions @ThomasAndrews

Comment: More generally, you can show $G_a,$ as defined in my first argument, must have all  orbits of size $|G_a|$ except for the fixed value $a.$

Comment: I know this, but this won't give contradictions. @ThomasAndrews

Comment: If use Burnside's lemma, suppose $|A|=k, |G|=n$, then the number of orbits $r=\frac{k+n-1}{n}$, we can only conclude some constraint on the size of set $A$, which is $k=(r-1)\cdot n+1$. How do you prove it? @Joey

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea of GGplay in the comments works. Since all non-identity elements have exactly one fixed point, and the number $r$ of orbits is the average of the fixed points of the elements (which I believe is not a result of Burnside), we get $r=(|A|+|G|-1)/|G|$, so

$$|A| = (r-1)|G|+1.$$

Since the length of each orbit is a factor of $|G|$, there cannot be more than one orbit of length less than $|G|$, because two such orbits would have combined length at most $|G|$ making the total length at most $|G| + (r-2)|G| < |A|$.

So there must be $r-1$ orbits of length $|G|$ and one of length $1$, which proves the result.

Comment: Great, thank you a lot!